# Math symbols not showing while using fontspec

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, errors, fontspec

Math, symbols are not showing when i am using the `fontspec` package. Here i paste the command and output please tell me as to how i can rectify this.

Command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,amssymb]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath,fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{URW Bookman L}
\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(a^{1/n}-1\right) &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a^{1/x}-1}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{\ln(a)/x}-1}{\frac{1}{x}}\\    &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{x^2}\ln(a)e^{\ln(a)/x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\\    &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\ln(a)e^{\ln(a)/x} = \ln(a).
\end{align*}
So there *is* a pointwise limit, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(a) = \ln(a)$.
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

--

**ADDED- LOG FILE**

```
his is XeTeXk, Version 3.141592-2.2-0.996 (Web2C 7.5.6) (format=xelatex 2010.7.11)  8 DEC 2010 10:45
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**trial.tex
(./trial.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8h> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, arabic, basque, bulgarian, coptic, welsh, czech, slovak, german, ng
erman, danish, esperanto, spanish, catalan, galician, estonian, farsi, finnish,
 french, greek, monogreek, ancientgreek, croatian, hungarian, interlingua, ibyc
us, indonesian, icelandic, italian, latin, mongolian, dutch, norsk, polish, por
tuguese, pinyin, romanian, russian, slovenian, uppersorbian, serbian, swedish, 
turkish, ukenglish, ukrainian, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/revtex/revtex4.cls
Document Class: revtex4 2001/08/02 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for do
cumentation)
 Copyright (c) 2001 The American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <ogawa@teleport.com>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david@dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>.
ltxutil: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
Class revtex4 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 596.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count79
\@tbpen=\count80
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box26
Class revtex4 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1610.
ltxgrid: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
\c@linecount=\count81
\output=\toks14
\@protection@box=\box27
\@topmark@saved=\toks15
\footins@saved=\box28
\pagesofar=\box29
\footbox=\box30
\pagegrid@col=\count82
Class revtex4 Info: Incorporating package {textcase}  [1998/11/12 v0.06 Text on
ly upper/lower case changing (DPC)]. on input line 3682.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/xelatex/xetexurl/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2004/03/15  ver 3.1  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@affil=\count83
\absbox=\box31
\c@part=\count84
\c@section=\count85
\c@subsection=\count86
\c@subsubsection=\count87
\c@paragraph=\count88
\c@subparagraph=\count89
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\c@figure=\count90
\c@table=\count91

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2007/02/05 8.0 (PWD)
\bibhang=\skip43
\bibsep=\skip44
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 602.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count92
)
\widetext@top=\box32
\widetext@bot=\box33

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/revtex/revsymb.sty
Package: revsymb 2001/08/02 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documenta
tion)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 118.
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2002/01/22 v2.2d

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2001/10/25 v2.2f
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 132.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frak on input line 135.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bbb on input line 137.
))

Class revtex4 Warning: No Society specified, using generic APS style.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/revtex/aps.rtx
File: aps.rtx 2001/08/02 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentatio
n)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/revtex/10pt.rtx
File: 10pt.rtx 2001/08/02 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentati
on)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip45

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen102
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen103
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count93
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 211.
\uproot@=\count94
\leftroot@=\count95
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 307.
\classnum@=\count96
\DOTSCASE@=\count97
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 379.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 382.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 467.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box34
\strutbox@=\box35
\big@size=\dimen104
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 567.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 568.
\macc@depth=\count98
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count99
\dotsspace@=\muskip11
\c@parentequation=\count100
\dspbrk@lvl=\count101
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count102
\column@=\count103
\maxfields@=\count104
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen105
\alignsep@=\dimen106
\tagshift@=\dimen107
\tagwidth@=\dimen108
\totwidth@=\dimen109
\lineht@=\dimen110
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip46
\multlinetaggap=\skip47
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2666.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2667.
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2006/12/24 v1.13 Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2006/08/21 v0.3 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\c@zf@newff=\count105
\c@zf@index=\count106
\c@zf@script=\count107
\c@zf@language=\count108

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2005/08/06 v4.2 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count109
\calc@Bcount=\count110
\calc@Adimen=\dimen111
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen112
\calc@Askip=\skip48
\calc@Bskip=\skip49
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 75.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 76.
\calc@Ccount=\count111
\calc@Cskip=\skip50
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2006/11/18 v2.5f package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks22
\XKV@depth=\count112
File: xkeyval.tex 2006/11/18 v2.5f key=value parser (HA)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2007/01/14 v1.3 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 29.
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1enc.def
File: eu1enc.def 2006/08/13 v0.1a Experimental unicode font encoding
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 100.


(/usr/share/texmf/tex/xelatex/euenc/lm/eu1lmr.fd
File: eu1lmr.fd 2007/01/14 v1.3 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 1050.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 1053.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 1056.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 1059.

fontspec.cfg loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))
\c@zf@famc@Veljovic LT Book=\count113
Package fontspec Info: Defining font family for "Veljovic LT Book" with options
 [Mapping=tex-text] on input line 4.
Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Veljovic LT Book/B (it might not 
exist) on input line 4.
Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Veljovic LT Book/I (it might not 
exist) on input line 4.
Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Veljovic LT Book/BI (it might not
 exist) on input line 4.
 (./trial.aux)
\openout1 = `trial.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
Class revtex4 Info: Patching LaTeX tabular. on input line 6.
Class revtex4 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 6.
Class revtex4 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 6.
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/m/n on input line
 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/bx/n --> EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/m/n on input lin
e 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/m/n --> EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/m/n
 on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/m/n --> EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/m/n
 on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/m/it --> EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/m/it on input li
ne 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/bx/n --> EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/bx/n on input li
ne 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/lmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/lmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/m/n --> EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/bx/
n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/m/n --> EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/bx/
n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/bx/it --> EU1/VeljovicLTBook(0)/bx/it on input 
line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/lmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/lmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+lmm on input line 9.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd
File: omllmm.fd 2007/01/14 v1.3 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 9.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd
File: omslmsy.fd 2007/01/14 v1.3 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMX+lmex on input line 9.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd
File: omxlmex.fd 2007/01/14 v1.3 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 9.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2002/01/19 v2.2g AMS font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 9.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2002/01/19 v2.2g AMS font definitions
) [1] (./trial.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4577 strings out of 191470
 72073 string characters out of 1925444
 165455 words of memory out of 1500000
 7727 multiletter control sequences out of 10000+200000
 7134 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 1200000 for 2000
 605 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 29i,10n,43p,295b,187s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,6000p,200000b,15000s

Output written on trial.pdf (1 page).
```

**ERROR 2**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (TeX Live 2011/dev) (format=xelatex 2010.7.20)  9 DEC 2010 09:35
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**trial.tex
(./trial.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, po
lish, ukrainian, russian, hungarian, danish, indonesian, latin, uppersorbian, s
erbian, coptic, turkmen, portuguese, kurmanji, slovenian, pinyin, farsi, sanskr
it, icelandic, catalan, irish, basque, bulgarian, bokmal, nynorsk, mongolian, m
ongolianlmc, german, ngerman, swissgerman, latvian, welsh, ukenglish, usenglish
max, lithuanian, monogreek, greek, dutch, interlingua, slovak, finnish, german-
x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, esperanto, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hin
di, kannada, malayalam, marathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, galician, armen
ian, swedish, italian, ancientgreek, ibycus, estonian, romanian, arabic, lao, f
rench, czech, spanish, loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2010/07/14 v2.0b Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX


(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3names.sty
Package: l3names 2010/07/11 v1981 L3 Experimental Naming Scheme for TeX Primiti
ves
)
Package: expl3 2010/07/13 v1982 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count88
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3basics.sty
Package: l3basics 2010/06/07 v1942 L3 Experimental basic definitions
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3expan.sty
Package: l3expan 2010/06/10 v1948 L3 Experimental Argument Expansion module
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3tl.sty
Package: l3tl 2010/05/22 v1919 L3 Experimental Token Lists
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3intexpr.sty
Package: l3intexpr 2010/06/15 v1957 L3 Integer Expressions
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3quark.sty
Package: l3quark 2010/03/21 v1853 L3 Experimental Quark Commands
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3seq.sty
Package: l3seq 2010/03/29 v1879 L3 Experimental sequences and stacks
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3toks.sty
Package: l3toks 2010/05/25 v1933 L3 Experimental Token Registers
\l_tmpb_toks=\toks14
\l_tmpc_toks=\toks15
\g_tmpa_toks=\toks16
\g_tmpb_toks=\toks17
\g_tmpc_toks=\toks18
\c_empty_toks=\toks19
\l_tl_replace_toks=\toks20
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3int.sty
Package: l3int 2010/05/25 v1933 L3 Experimental Integer module
\l_tmpa_int=\count89
\l_tmpb_int=\count90
\l_tmpc_int=\count91
\g_tmpa_int=\count92
\g_tmpb_int=\count93
\c_max_int=\count94
\g_tl_inline_level_int=\count95
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3prg.sty
Package: l3prg 2010/03/21 v1853 L3 Experimental control structures
\g_prg_inline_level_int=\count96
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3clist.sty
Package: l3clist 2010/03/29 v1878 L3 Experimental comma separated lists
\g_clist_inline_level_int=\count97
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3token.sty
Package: l3token 2010/04/11 v1890 L3 Experimental token investigation and manip
ulation
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3prop.sty
Package: l3prop 2010/03/21 v1857 L3 Experimental Property Lists
\g_prop_inline_level_int=\count98
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3msg.sty
Package: l3msg 2010/03/23 v1866 L3 Experimental LaTeX Messages module
\l_msg_redirect_classes_prop=\toks21
\l_msg_redirect_names_prop=\toks22
\l_msg_redirect_fatal_prop=\toks23
\l_msg_redirect_error_prop=\toks24
\l_msg_redirect_warning_prop=\toks25
\l_msg_redirect_info_prop=\toks26
\l_msg_redirect_log_prop=\toks27
\l_msg_redirect_trace_prop=\toks28
\l_msg_redirect_none_prop=\toks29
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3io.sty
Package: l3io 2010/05/22 v1923 L3 Experimental i/o module
\g_iow_streams_prop=\toks30
\g_ior_streams_prop=\toks31
\l_iow_stream_int=\count99
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3skip.sty
Package: l3skip 2010/05/25 v1933 L3 Experimental skip registers
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip43
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpc_skip=\skip45
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip47
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen103
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpc_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpd_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3box.sty
Package: l3box 2010/05/22 v1919 L3 Experimental Box module
\l_tmpb_box=\box26
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3keyval.sty
Package: l3keyval 2010/04/11 v1890 L3 Experimental keyval processing
\l_KV_level_int=\count100
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3keys.sty
Package: l3keys 2010/05/24 v1931 L3 Experimental key-value support
\l_keys_choice_int=\count101
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3precom.sty
Package: l3precom 2010/02/09 v1793 L3 Experimental precompilation module
\g_gen_sym_int=\count102
\g_ggen_sym_int=\count103
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3xref.sty
Package: l3xref 2010/02/09 v1786 L3 Experimental cross referencing
\g_xref_all_curr_immediate_fields_prop=\toks32
\g_xref_all_curr_deferred_fields_prop=\toks33
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3file.sty
Package: l3file 2010/03/21 v1853 L3 Experimental file loading
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3fp.sty
Package: l3fp 2010/07/08 v1979 L3 Experimental floating-point operations
\l_fp_input_a_integer_int=\count104
\l_fp_input_a_decimal_int=\count105
\l_fp_input_b_integer_int=\count106
\l_fp_input_b_decimal_int=\count107
\l_fp_input_a_sign_int=\count108
\l_fp_input_b_sign_int=\count109
\l_fp_split_sign_int=\count110
\l_fp_mul_a_i_int=\count111
\l_fp_mul_a_ii_int=\count112
\l_fp_mul_a_iii_int=\count113
\l_fp_mul_a_iv_int=\count114
\l_fp_mul_a_v_int=\count115
\l_fp_mul_a_vi_int=\count116
\l_fp_mul_b_i_int=\count117
\l_fp_mul_b_ii_int=\count118
\l_fp_mul_b_iii_int=\count119
\l_fp_mul_b_iv_int=\count120
\l_fp_mul_b_v_int=\count121
\l_fp_mul_b_vi_int=\count122
\l_fp_mul_output_int=\count123
\l_fp_div_count_int=\count124
\l_fp_div_offset_int=\count125
\l_fp_output_sign_int=\count126
\l_fp_output_integer_int=\count127
\l_fp_output_decimal_int=\count128
\l_fp_round_discard_int=\count129
\l_fp_round_position_int=\count130
\l_fp_tmp_int=\count131
\c_one_hundred_million=\count132
\c_one_thousand_million=\count133
\l_fp_tmp_dim=\dimen109
\l_fp_round_precision_int=\count134
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count135
\calc@Bcount=\count136
\calc@Adimen=\dimen110
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen111
\calc@Askip=\skip48
\calc@Bskip=\skip49
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 76.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 77.
\calc@Ccount=\count137
\calc@Cskip=\skip50
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xpackages/xbase/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2010/05/23 v1927 Generic document command parser
\c_xparse_shorthands_prop=\toks34
\l_xparse_m_args_int=\count138
\l_xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count139
\l_xparse_processor_int=\count140
\l_xparse_total_args_int=\count141
)
! I can't find file `binhex.tex'.
l.22 \input binhex.tex 
                        % before expl syntax!
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: 
! Emergency stop.
l.22 \input binhex.tex 
                        % before expl syntax!
End of file on the terminal!


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4080 strings out of 494556
 70746 string characters out of 3159734
 98441 words of memory out of 3000000
 7329 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 669 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 38i,0n,35p,201b,53s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: You can use indentation by four spaces or the `101010`-button to mark a block of code. Could you please remove all the white space from the picture.

Comment: You specified the `pdftex` tag. Does that mean that you compile the document with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Caramdir: I don't know how to remove the white spaces. Next if yes i compile the document with pdflatex

Comment: Use your image editing program of choice (Windows Paint if you must).

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit, but here's a trimmed version: http://i.imgur.com/gG1se.png.

Comment: @caramdir: I don't use windows i use fedora

Comment: I don't know what the image program that fedora includes in its default install is. Probably GIMP. @Ben: thanks

Comment: Please don't post entire log files here. Use a service like [Gist](http://gist.github.com) to link to a large amount of text.

Answer (score 6):

Update your system. fontspec 2006/12/24 v1.13  is ancient. The current version is fontspec 2010/11/17 v2.1e. And your amsfonts has version amsfonts 2001/10/25 v2.2f while current is amsfonts 2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support.

Comment: @Ulrike: How do i update it. Please provide me some details. The yum update command doesnt update the system

Comment: @Chandru1 it is quite easy to install [Tex Live](http://tug.org/texlive/) manually (i.e. not via the package manager).

Comment: @ulrike: it still shows some error which i have added

Comment: Why do you copy an almost unreadable complete log-file? The error message is quite clear `I can't find file binhex.tex`. binhex is part of the kastrup package. So install it with the texlive package manager.

Comment: @Chandru1: you appear to have upgraded to TeXLive 2011 by mistake.  That's not actually been released yet.  You should remove that and upgrade to TeXLive 2010 instead.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compile documents with `fontspec` included with pdfLaTeX. It should just quit with the following error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
! 
! Fatal fontspec error: "not-pdftex"
! 
! Requires XeTeX or LuaTeX to function!
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

`fontspec` is designed to use the font handling capabilities of XeTeX and LuaTeX. I cannot be used with `pdflatex`.

Comment: So how should i compile

Comment: with `xelatex` or `lualatex` (and preferably the newest versions installed).

Comment: You mean to say in terminal i should have xelatex filename.tex

Comment: @chandru1: yes.

Comment: No it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Your second log output has:

```
I can't find file `binhex.tex'.
l.22 \input binhex.tex % before expl syntax!
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
! Emergency stop.
l.22 \input binhex.tex % before expl syntax!
End of file on the terminal!
```

which suggests that you are missing a file called `binhex.tex`.  On my system (TeXLive2010), it is in: `texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex`.  This is the `kastrup` package on CTAN: [kastrup](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/kastrup/).

That this is missing suggests that your TeX installation is not as complete as it could be.  I recommend upgrading to TL2010.  Alternatively, there is probably a package to install from your distribution (Fedora or RedHat, I guess) which will include it.  Some distributions chop up the TeX installation into smaller packages as the whole lot can use up quite a bit of space.

Comment: The first line of the log say "TeX Live 2011/dev". So "up"grading to TL2010 is perhaps not the correct advice ;-).

Comment: @Ulrike: Hmmm.  Perhaps I should have said "down"grading.  Looking at, say, the line for `xparse` I see in the above log `Package: xparse 2010/05/23 v1927` but on my (TL2010) system, I get `xparse 2010/09/20 v2037`.  I'd be surprised if the (dev) TL2011 is using **earlier** versions than TL2010 so my current guess is that the "up"grade (implied in the comment to your answer) did not work properly.

Comment: @Ulrike: Actually, how did Chandru manage to upgrade to TL2011???

Comment: No idea where he/she got the 2011/dev. I'm a miktex user. Regarding the versions: a basic install of miktex doesn't contain the newest versions either. You have to run an update after the installation to fetch them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the cm-default option? Fontspec (at least version 1.13 that ships still today on modern CentOS) uses option `lm-default` (latin modern) over cm (computer-modern) for math symbols. If you're using an older version without lm support this would cause your problem.

```
\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
```